# HTML Form not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, search

I have a form like follows:

```
<form action="" method="GET" data-ronsor-url="http://web-search.tk">
<input id="q">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

But nothing is submitted.
if the form was at http://web-search.tk/?q=mysearch, when the form is submitted, the url is http://web-search.tk/?, why is this. It worked before.

**Note: I will delete this question if I get more than 1 downvotes**

Comment: Show us your PHP. Plus this `<input id="q">` seems incomplete.

Comment: I have way to much php to post.

Comment: Argg.. see the answer below. Missing `name` attribute.

Comment: You have no inputs with a `name` attribute.  `<input name="q" id="q">`.

Comment: It's most likely to be in your PHP then. What's changed since your last one worked? Check that.

Comment: It never worked. That's the problem.

Comment: index.php?q=php+help works

Comment: ***"why is this. It worked before."*** <= ???

Comment: -1 All you needed to do is put 2+2 together. The first answer given told you to name your input. Your troubleshooting skills = NULL.

Comment: The form on the homepage works. But the form on another page fails < it never worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a name attribute to the form input:

```
<form action="" method="GET" data-ronsor-url="http://web-search.tk">
    <input id="q" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

I am not quite sure what are you trying to achieve but if you set the action attr = http://web-search.tk it performs the search at http://web-search.tk website.

You might be depending on some js if you wish to perform the search at your website, but again I'm not quite sure what's yor goal!

Good luck, hope it helps

Comment: Now it works. Accepting now.

Comment: Can you provide info what `data-ronsor-url` is

Comment: that's my domain identifier, I use this in my tracking script

Comment: For what it's worth, if you leave the `action` attribute of the `form` empty (or even just omit it), the form will be submitted to the "current" page.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the form `action` and the `name` of the input (query) field (instead of, or in addition to, the `id`):

```
<form action="http://web-search.tk" method="GET">
<input name="q">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: It seems to work on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3vjc/
Are you sure this is the exact HTML you're using? Can you make an edit with your updated HTML?

Comment: +1 because of added information *"(instead of, or in addition to, the id)"* OP would have been able to put 2+2 together.

Comment: @anonman "It" probably didn't work because you copy-pasted code. The code snippet provided here was just a demonstration that your `input` needs a `name` attribute in order to be included in the HTTP request when the form gets submitted.